# cargar imagen de la base de datos con el control image asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagen

en el proyecto que estoy realizando debo de cargar una imagen que esta almacenada en la base de datos, esto lo hice a través de un fileupload y esa unica imagen debe de cargar en un asp:Image, he investigado varios pero usan picture box o lo hacen con un grid view, espero me puedan ayudar

Este es el codigo que utilizo para guardar la imagen a la base de datos

```
int Tamanio = FileUploadS1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] ImagenOriginal = new byte[Tamanio];
            FileUploadS1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(ImagenOriginal, 0, Tamanio);
            Bitmap ImagenOriginalBinaria = new Bitmap(FileUploadS1.PostedFile.InputStream);

            SqlConnection conexionsql = new SqlConnection(cadena);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Prueba_WebSIIE set Prueba_S1_Imagen = (@imagen)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ImagenOriginal;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conexionsql;
            conexionsql.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: y en esa base de datos están  guardados como blob o como string codificado en base64?

Comment: A base 64, este es el metodo que uso para guardarlo, ya puse en la publicacion el metodo que uso